# Is it possible to determine shape and scale for a gamma distribution from a mean and confidence interval?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

Having the 95% confidence interval and mean for a distribution and knowing nothing else (other than the data is skewed and will likely follow a gamma distribution) is there any way to determine the shape and scale of that gamma distribution? If not, what are the minimum data you would need to determine these?

Comment: Do you mean the 95% confidence interval centered on the mean?

Comment: In general, if you have two unknowns, you need two independent equations to form a system to solve them. In your case, if you have functions of point estimatiors (the confidence limits) and equate to the realizations, you can solve the point estimates of the parameters out.

Comment: @BGM can you expand on that a bit? Lets say I know the SD. Where would I go from there?

Comment: @JackM Yes. The CI is centered on the mean.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the mean is $\mu$ and the standard deviation is $\sigma$, then the shape parameter of a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) is $\dfrac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}$ and the scale parameter is $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\mu}$, making the corresponding rate parameter $\dfrac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$

As an illustration of what is possible, suppose you knew that the mean is $40$ and you had an interval of $[30,50]$ representing about $2$ standard deviations either side of the mean

Then the standard deviation is about $\frac{50-40}{2}=5$, and the variance is therefore about $5^2=25$

For a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $k$ and scale parameter $\theta$, the mean would be $k\theta$ and the variance $k\theta^2$, suggesting with these numbers that $\theta \approx \frac{25}{40} = 0.625$ (equivalent to a rate of $1.6$) and $k \approx \frac{40^2}{25}=64$

As a check, we can look at the corresponding interval for these parameters in R

```
> pgamma(50,shape=64,scale=0.625) - pgamma(30,shape=64,scale=0.625)
[1] 0.9553145
> c(qgamma(0.025,shape=64,scale=0.625),qgamma(0.975,shape=64,scale=0.625))
[1] 30.80487 50.37773
```

which shows this approach is not exact, but is not that far away.

$k=59.3749$ and $\theta=0.66312$ would get you closer to the confidence interval with $2.5\%$ each side but at the cost (due to the asymmetry of the Gamma distribution) of a corresponding mean of $39.372$ rather than $40$

Comment: How do you know that the standard deviation is approx. $\frac{50-40}{2}$?  I'm not following that.

Comment: @entpnerd *"suppose you knew that the mean is 40 and you had an interval of [30,50] representing about 2 standard deviations either side of the mean"* is saying $50$ is about two standard deviations above $40$, i.e. the standard deviation is half the difference so about $5$

Comment: Thanks @henry. I read that sentence before, but was still confused. But, I think that I might understand now.

Basically, what you're really saying is that if I have an upper bound representing approx. 2 standard-deviations away from the mean called $e_{max}$, then it follows that $2 \sigma = e_{max} - \mu$. Is that correct? Is there some formula referenced somewhere for this? I think that I've only previously seen the standard deviation formula $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum{(x-\mu)^2}}{N}}$.

Comment: @entpnerd - the original question starts with the confidence interval (and mean) and then asks how to find the parameters of a gamma distribution.  My answer was based on supposing that the confidence interval was approximately $[\mu - 2 \sigma, \mu + 2 \sigma]$. As I said, this approach is not exact, but is not that far away, at least in the example I gave